I can not upload Image to the Appwrite storage React-Native Expo
I am trying to upload and update user avatar from my profile screen but when i choose the image from my gallery or cam i get that error:
Error updating avatar: [TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined]
Error uploading file: [Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined]
my appwrite file
import {
  Account,
  Avatars,
  Client,
  Databases,
  ID,
  Query,
  Storage,
} from "react-native-appwrite";

const client = new Client();

client
  .setEndpoint(appwriteConfig.endpoint)
  .setProject(appwriteConfig.projectId)
  .setPlatform(appwriteConfig.platform);

const account = new Account(client);
const avatars = new Avatars(client);
const databases = new Databases(client);
const storage = new Storage(client);


export async function getAccount() {
  try {
    const currentAccount = await account.get();

    if (!currentAccount) throw Error();
    return currentAccount;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}

export const getCurrentUser = async () => {
  try {
    const currentAccount = await getAccount();
    if (!currentAccount) throw new Error("Account not found");

    const currentUser = await databases.listDocuments(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.userCollectionId,
      [Query.equal("accountId", currentAccount.$id)]
    );

    if (!currentUser.documents.length) {
      throw new Error("User not found in database");
    }
    return currentUser.documents[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error fetching current user: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const updateAvatar = async (file) => {
  if (!file) throw new Error("No file provided");

  try {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    console.log("current account", currentUser, currentUser.$id);
    if (!currentUser || !currentUser.$id) {
      throw new Error("User is not authenticated. Cannot upload file.");
    }

    console.log("Uploading file:", file);

    const uploadedFile = await storage.createFile(
      appwriteConfig.storageId,
      ID.unique(),
      file
    );
    console.log("Uploaded file response:", uploadedFile);
    const fileId = uploadedFile.$id;

    const fileUrl = storage.getFilePreview(
      appwriteConfig.storageId,
      fileId,
      2000,
      2000,
      "top",
      100
    );

    console.log("File URL:", fileUrl);
    console.log("Current User ID:", currentUser.$id);

    const updatedUser = await databases.updateDocument(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.userCollectionId,
      currentUser.$id,
      {
        avatar: fileUrl,
      }
    );
    console.log("Current User ID:", currentUser.$id);

    return updatedUser;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating avatar:", error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};

my profile screen that i am tryin to upload profile picture
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Modal,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { icons } from "@/constants";
import ProfileButton from "@/components/ProfileButton";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { signOut, updateAvatar } from "@/lib/appwrite";
import { useGlobalContext } from "@/context/GlobalProvider";
import CustomButton from "@/components/CustomButton";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const Profile = () => {
  const { user, setUser, setIsLoggedIn } = useGlobalContext();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const openImagePickerModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleImagePicked = async (pickerResult) => {
    if (!pickerResult.canceled) {
      const pickedImage = pickerResult.assets[0].uri;
      console.log("Selected image URI:", pickedImage);
      try {
        const response = await updateAvatar({
          uri: pickedImage,
          type: pickerResult.assets[0].type,
          name: pickerResult.assets[0].fileName || "profile.png",
        });
        console.log("Uploaded file response:", response);
        if (response) {
          setImage(pickedImage);
        } else {
          console.log("File upload failed");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
      }
    }
    closeModal();
  };

  const pickImageFromCamera = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });
    await handleImagePicked(result);
  };

  const pickImageFromGallery = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });
    await handleImagePicked(result);
  };

  const navigateSettings = () => {
    router.push("/yourprofile/settings");
  };

  const navigateYourProfile = () => {
    router.push("/yourprofile/yourProfile");
  };

  const logOut = async () => {
    await signOut();
    setUser(null);
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    router.replace("/sign-in");
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 bg-primary">
      <View className="p-4 flex-1">
        <ScrollView>
          <View className="mb-20 items-center">
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={openImagePickerModal}>
              <View className="w-24 h-24 rounded-full bg-gray-800 justify-center items-center mb-2.5 mt-5">
                {image ? (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: image }}
                    className="w-full h-full rounded-full"
                  />
                ) : (
                  <Image source={icons.profile} className="w-16 h-16" />
                )}
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text className="text-white text-lg">{user?.username}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={openImagePickerModal}>
              <Image source={icons.camera} className="w-6 h-6 mt-2" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <ProfileButton text="Your Profile" onPress={navigateYourProfile} />
          <ProfileButton text="Settings" onPress={navigateSettings} />
        </ScrollView>
        <View className="relative mb-[80px]">
          <CustomButton title="Log Out" handlePress={logOut} />
        </View>
      </View>

      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
      >
        <View className="flex-1 justify-center items-center bg-black bg-opacity-50">
          <View className="bg-white w-80 p-4 rounded-lg">
            <Text className="text-lg font-bold mb-4">Profile Photo</Text>
            <View className="flex-row justify-around mb-4">
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImageFromCamera}>
                <View className="flex-col items-center">
                  <Image source={icons.camera} className="w-8 h-8 mb-2" />
                  <Text>Kamera</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImageFromGallery}>
                <View className="flex-col items-center">
                  <Image source={icons.gallery} className="w-8 h-8 mb-2" />
                  <Text>Galeri</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={closeModal}>
                <View className="flex-col items-center">
                  <Image source={icons.trash} className="w-8 h-8 mb-2" />
                  <Text>Remove</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <CustomButton title="İptal" handlePress={closeModal} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Profile;

I have checked and logged 'pickedImage', 'currentUser', 'currentAccount', 'currentUser.$id', 'file'. I got required responses from all of them. But when i logged 'uploadedFile' i get undefined. The image did not uploading so i think i got '$id' undefined from:
const fileId = uploadedFile.$id;

    const fileUrl = storage.getFilePreview(
      appwriteConfig.storageId,
      fileId,
      2000,
      2000,
      "top",
      100
    );

